# Does a following pronoun ALWAYS refer to the Subject of the previous sentence?

Tags: pronouns

Q1. "Mr and Mrs Smith loved their children so much. And **they** were very happy."

What does "they" refer to?

Q2. "Mr and Mrs Smith loved their children so much. But **they** were not happy at all."

What does "they" refer to?

Q3. The point of my question is:

"Does a following pronoun **ALWAYS** refer to the **Subject** of the previous sentence?"

"Can't a following pronoun refer to the **Object** of the previous sentence?"

Comment: Without further clarification, _they_ could be either the parents or the children. If the subject was only one person, _they_ would clearly mean the children.

Comment: @KateBunting: The referent of ***they*** isn't necessarily fixed by one of possible targets being singular, because of potential "singular they" usages. *The parent who was awarded custody of the children said **they** were very happy* is "three-way ambiguous" as to whether s/he claimed the ***children*** were happy, or ***him/herself***, or ***all of them collectively*** were happy.

Comment: Compare "The car hit a fence, and it got a broken headlight." and "My car hit a fence, and it got a broken paling".

Comment: @FumbleFingers True. I was thinking of "Mr. Smith loved his children..."

Comment: @KateBunting: I know - and I had to think for a moment before I could come up with a context where the referent of the possessive was ***a single person of unspecified gender*** who could reasonably be interpreted as an alternative to ***the children*** in such contexts. Until "gender-agnostic" ***the parent*** floated into my consciousness, I was positively floundering there! :)

Comment: @mystery You must know that it's ambiguous, so why bother to ask?

Comment: I expected the answers that Q1: "Mr and Mrs Smith", Q2: "their children." And I did want to know if a following pronoun can refer to not only the  subject of the previous sentence but also the object of the previous sentence depending on the context. And I got a clear clue from Ms. Kate Bunting and Mr. Peter's examples. Mr. FumbleFingers, thank you for your concern again. And Mr. BillJ, Sorry if I bothered you. Thank you, everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Does a following pronoun ALWAYS refer to the Subject of the previous sentence?"

No.

Each pronoun should have a clear and unmistakable noun antecedent, otherwise there will be error of vague pronoun reference.

Neither Q1 nor Q2 has a clear single and unmistakable noun antecedent.

To correct this,  Q1 and Q2 should have their pronouns, 'they', replaced with their nouns intended to be represented.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your help:) By the way, aren't "Mr and Mrs Smith' and "their children" noun antecedents? Are you meaning that the sentences each have TWO noun antecedents not ONE , so that's the problem?

Comment: I learned that in case of ambiguity it refers to the subject of the previous sentence. But many Americans ignore this rule I think

Answer (score 0):

Not always, but in case of ambiguity, like in your two examples, then the subject of the previous sentence has priority. That's what I learned.